# ¿Qué salió mal con el código?

Tags: python

Quiero que el titulo lleve color pero me muestra una especie de fusion entre el texto y ANSI, estuve tratando de gráficar algunas funciones con titulo y algunas etiquetas pero sigo teniendo este problema incluso usando colorama y termcolor.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from termcolor import colored    # Busca una Libreria de Colores

x1 = np.arange(-4, 4.01, 0.01) # Dominio de las Funciones
x2 = np.arange(-11, 11.01, 0.01) 

y1 = 7*x1**7 - 5*x1**4 + 3*x1**2 + 1     # Funciones
y2 = -7*x2**7 + 5*x2**4 - 3*x2**2 - 1

plt.figure(figsize=(10,11))       # Tamaño
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-17,17)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-5, 6, 1)) 
plt.yticks(np.arange(-17, 18, 1))

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'c_')          # Grafica funciones
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'd-.') 


tit= colored('Funciones Polinómicas de 7° Grado', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])

plt.title(tit, fontweight='bold')        # Coloca un Título y unas Etiquetas con Negritas
plt.xlabel('Eje X', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Eje Y', fontweight='bold')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Modificando tu codigo cuando dice "from termcolor import colored" por import termcolor y  cuando dices "tit=colored" por tit=tempcolor.cprint. Si me funciona, me sale un rojito subrayado con una especie de fucsia. Probado en replit.com. (No quise instalar libs que no uso). Mira a ver si en tu Sistema Operativo y IDE te va. Suerte

Comment: Y si lo deseas con las matplotlib.pyplot ya puedes introducir color en los textos y titulos. Ver la documentación. Quiza ni te hace falta la otra libreria

Answer (score 0):

Como su nombre ya deja entrever, la biblioteca `colorterm` sirve para volcar texto coloreado **en terminales** (o consolas de texto).

Para ello hace uso de códigos de escape ANSI. Lo que hace simplemente es crear una cadena de texto que lleva "incrustados" en ciertos lugares códigos de escape. Cuando haces `print()` a una terminal, python simplemente envía los bytes que componen la cadena. Si la terminal es compatible ANSI, al recibir los códigos de activación de color, obedecerá y el resultado será texto coloreado. Si la terminal en cambio no es compatible ANSI, mostrará esos códigos sin más, como si fueran parte del texto a mostrar.

Así, cuando haces:

```
tit= colored('Funciones Polinómicas de 7° Grado', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
```

Lo que resulta en `txt` es la cadena:

```
'\x1b[5m\x1b[7m\x1b[31mFunciones Polinómicas de 7° Grado\x1b[0m'
```

La secuencia `\x1b` representa el código de escape que señala a la terminal que los caracteres siguientes `[5m` por ejemplo, son un comando de cambio de color. Las terminales no ANSI ignorarán el código de escape y simplemente mostrarían:

```
[5m[7m[31mFunciones Polinómicas de 7° Grado[0m
```

Naturalmente una gráfica matplotlib no es una terminal, por lo que entraría en este segundo caso (tal vez incluso mostraría con algún símbolo raro los propios escapes).

La forma de modificar los colores en matplotlib sería así:

```
tit= 'Funciones Polinómicas de 7° Grado'
title_obj = plt.title(tit, fontweight='bold')
plt.setp(title_obj, color='w', backgroundcolor="red")
```

Lo que da lugar a la siguiente figura:

[image: Resultado]

Lo que no es posible conseguir (y yo diría ¡menos mal!) es el atributo Blink para hacer que el título de la figura parpadee.